# Force all textview in app to display numbers in en-us format android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview

I have an issue when the user changes his phone to Arabic and reopen my application the numbers are in Arabic, is there a way to force all the app to convert all textview to accept Locale.US?
maybe set the style same as font text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NumberFormat** class which offers to format of numbers based on a given Locale.
Given code in Kotlin

```
val number = 10
val formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US)
text_view.text = formatter.format(number)
```

Or, in case if you want to change number as per to its currency formatting, you can do the same with the help of same class.

```
val formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)
text_view.text = formatter.format(number)
```

Comment: yes but what im asking if there is away to force all the app textview to set numberFormat as local.us, instead of going through each text in app and changing it

Comment: yes, you can change this from styles.xml or theme.xml, under style of textview, you can do this and it will forcibly apply to all textviews under your project.

Comment: and how to do that from style?